# How to pass parameter between two javascript files in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express js and i want to pass parameter from one javascript file to other. How can I achieve this??

The two files are 1. process.js

```js
var WebPageTest = require('webpagetest');
var wpt = new WebPageTest('server address');
var data_url;


exports.process =  function (req, res){

    
    //Running the test
    wpt.runTest(script,{runs: 1},function(err, data) {
        console.log("<----STARTING TEST---->");
        if(err){ console.log(err);}
        data_url = data.data.summaryCSV;
        console.log('-----------');
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');
    });
    res.render('index.jade',{par: 'welcome to webpagetest performance, the tests are running in background.'})
};
```

storedata.js is here

```js
var request = require('request');
var CSV = require('csv-string');
var moment = require('moment');
var process = require('./process.js');


exports.storedata = function(req,res){

    var URL;
    var loadTime;
    var TTFB;
    var TTFB1;
    var date;
    var date1;
    var date2;
    var db;
    console.log(process.process.data_url);

    request({uri:process.process.data_url,method:'GET'}, function (error,response,body)  {
                //console.log('----@@@@@@----');
                //console.log(response.headers);
                console.log('----@@@@@@----');
                //console.log(response);
                if (error) {
                    console.log('got an error' + error);
                }
                //console.log(response);
                //console.log(body);
                var data = body;
                console.log('here is the body');
                console.log('----@@@@@@----');
                console.log(body);


                CSV.forEach(data, ',', function (row, index) {
                    if (index == 1 || index == 2) {
                        URL = row[0];
                        loadTime = row[1];

                        TTFB = row[2];
                        TTFB1 = parseInt(TTFB);

                        date = new Date(row[59] * 1000);
                        month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
                        month = month.toString();
                        var day = date.getUTCDate();
                        day = day.toString();
                        var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
                        year = year.toString();
                        date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                        date1 = new Date(date);
                        date2 = moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                        //console.log(loadTime);
                        var app_re = new RegExp(/^https\:\/\/some-url/);
                        var staging_re = new RegExp(/^https\:\/\/some-url2/);
                        var webuinqa_re = new RegExp(/^https\:\/\/some-url3/);

                        // Writting into the databse for some-url
                        if(app_re.test(URL)){
                        var db = req.db;
                        var collection = db.get('app');
                        collection.insert({
                            "Date": date2,
                            "TTFB": TTFB1,
                            "loadTime": loadTime,
                            "Url": URL
                        }, function (err, doc) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                            }
                        });}

                        //Writting into the database for some-url2
                        if(staging_re.test(URL)){
                            var db = req.db;
                            var collection = db.get('staging');
                            collection.insert({
                                "Date": date2,
                                "TTFB": TTFB1,
                                "loadTime": loadTime,
                                "Url": URL
                            }, function (err, doc) {
                                if (err) {
                                    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                                }
                            });}

                        //Writting into the database for some-url3
                        if(webuinqa_re.test(URL)){
                            var db = req.db;
                            var collection = db.get('webuinqa');
                            collection.insert({
                                "Date": date2,
                                "TTFB": TTFB1,
                                "loadTime": loadTime,
                                "Url": URL
                            }, function (err, doc) {
                                if (err) {
                                    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                                }
                            });}
                        res.render('index', {title: "All the test Results have been added to the databases, Go to localhost/getData to get the graph"});
                        //res.redirect('/getData');
                    }
                });
    });
};
```

I want to pass parameter data_url in process.js file to storedata.js file so. I will use the value of data_url in method request in storedata.js.

Comment: if both javascript files are loaded on the same html page, all vars(global) or functions are available, it does make very difficult to debug if ever something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

In your **storedata.js**

```
module.exports = function(data_url) {
  // ...
}
```

In **process.js**:

```
var request = require('request');
var CSV = require('csv-string');
var moment = require('moment');
// The path like this assumes storedata.js and process.js
// are in the same folder.
var storeData = require('./storedata');

exports.process =  function (req, res){
  var URL;
  var loadTime;
  var TTFB;
  var TTFB1;
  var date;
  var date1;
  var date2;
  var db;
  var data_url;

  // initiating the test
  var WebPageTest = require('webpagetest');
  var wpt = new WebPageTest('server-address');

  //Running the test
  wpt.runTest(script,function(err, data) {
      //console.log("hello -->",err || data);

      data_url = data.data.summaryCSV;
      console.log('-----------');
      console.log(data_url);
      console.log('-----------');

      // Once your data_url is ready
      storeData(data_url);
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, here is a possible solution.

```
var WebPageTest = require('webpagetest');
var wpt = new WebPageTest('server address');
var data_url;

exports.process =  function (req, res){
    //Running the test
    wpt.runTest(script,{runs: 1},function(err, data) {
        console.log("<----STARTING TEST---->");
        if(err){ console.log(err);}
        data_url = data.data.summaryCSV;
        console.log('-----------');
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');
    });
    res.render('index.jade',{par: 'welcome to webpagetest performance, the tests are running in background.'})
};

// Create another method that is able to return the saved data.
exports.getSavedDataURL = function() { return data_url; }
```

Then in storedata.js

```
exports.storedata = function(req,res){
    var URL;
    var loadTime;
    var TTFB;
    var TTFB1;
    var date;
    var date1;
    var date2;
    var db;
    // 
    var url = process.getSavedDataURL();

    request({uri:url,method:'GET'}, function (error,response,body)  {
```

Comment: just to confirm. Dont you think your answer is reverse of what i am trying. I am trying to pass variable from process.js to storedata.js, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, could you post the rest of the code in process.js and storedata.js? I suspect it has to do with the way your export your modules. As for your other question, the logic is that `var storedata` contains your method, that is why I use the `require()`, then it is triggered in the last line of the code above and passes the variable from **process.js** to **storedata.js**. Here is a [LINK](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) that might help you understand the relationship between files when exporting modules in node.js.

Comment: I have provided with all the codes you asked, please tell where should i head to .

Comment: I see, so I notice two problems: 1) The method `process.process` is never instantiated. So when you try `console.log(process.process.data_url);` in your **storedata.js**, this will return `undefined`. 2) More importantly, the order in which you are trying to call your methods is problematic due to the async call you are doing to the WebPageTest API. Everything in your **storedata.js** depends on what you get from the test, so it should only run after you get the results from *WebPageTest*. For that reason, you should consider working with callbacks (as code above) or promises.

Comment: Basically these two js files are two end points or entry points in my project, first i call process.js and after some time(like 15-20 min) i call storedata.js, so i dont think async nature of node here will do any problem for me.

Comment: Ok I think I understand better what you are trying to do. The problem now is that in the code you have in **storedata.js** you are treating **process.js** as a module that you import inside the storedata endpoint. The way it is now, it is not waiting "15-20 min". Even if you entered the process.js as an endpoint earlier. See my update for a possible solution to this.